# how do I split a file into chunks by regexp line separators?

Tags: linux, shell, one-liner

I would like to have a Linux oneliner that runs a "split" command in a slightly different way -- rather than by splitting the file into smaller files by using a constant number of lines or bytes, it will split the file according to a regexp separator that identifies where to insert the breaks and start a new file.

The problem is that most pipe commands work on one stream and can't split a stream into multiple files, unless there is some command that does that.

The closest I got to was:

```
cat myfile |
perl -pi -e 's/theseparatingregexp/SPLITHERE/g' |
split -l 1 -t SPLITHERE - myfileprefix
```

but it appears that split command cannot take multi-character delimeters.

Comment: Better give us a sample input and expected output

Comment: Have you considered using `awk` or `sed`? E.g., `sed 's/regexp' input_file | split -d - unique_string`

Comment: `Linux oneliner` Note: you can take _any_ script, convert it to md5, and do `echo abcedf | mdsum -d | bash`. Any Bash script can be converted to a oneliner. `The closest I got to was:` Perl is a full programming language. Just write it in perl. Read the file line by line and split it. Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15662/splitting-text-files-based-on-a-regular-expression https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599792/how-do-i-split-a-file-each-time-a-regular-expression-occurs